# GDB issue when using enum with type definition in c++

Tags: c++, enums, gdb

I have an `enum` with an explicit underlying type definition like this:

```
enum test : uint16_t
{
    test_x = 0x7fff, // 0111 1111 1111 1111
    test_y = 0x8000  // 1000 0000 0000 0000
};
```

And variables in my code that are assigned the `enum` values like this:

```
test num1 = test_x;
test num2 = test_y;
```

When I try to look at the value using GDB, I get this kind of result:

```
(gdb) print num1
$1 = test_x
(gdb) print num2
$2 = (test_y | unknown: -65536)
```

Why is `num2` acting so strange? Its value is in the range of the type I declared,
so what is wrong with this configuration?

I will also point out that this happens not just with `uint16_t` but with `uint32_t` and the values `test_x = 0x7fffffff, test_y = 0x80000000`.

***Edit***

I am compiling with GNU GCC version: 9.3.0 on ARM processor platform and using GDB version 8.1.0.

Comment: Looks like a GDB bug to me. It seems to think the value is signed.

Comment: missing information about the gcc/gdb versions.
Typed enum is C++11 attribute, and supporting it in gdb began even later. In case you run with gdb version <7.8 - I believe you want to upgrade.

Comment: BTW not reproducible on gdb 11.1

Comment: Thank you for the comments. They were very helpful. I added the missing information to the question.
my GDB version is 8.1 so it might be too old for this feature. 
 I will try to upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question after getting some helpful pointers in the comments.

This turned out to really be a bug in the GDB version I was using.
upgrading to a newer version solves this issue.
(I upgraded from 8.1 to 10.2)

```
(gdb) print num1
$1 = test_x
(gdb) print num2
$2 = test_y
(gdb) show version
GNU gdb (GDB; JetBrains IDE bundle; build 157) 10.2
...
```